# ts.union for time series with a name pattern R

Tags: r, time-series, environment-variables

I have some time series that in the name have a suffix "_edg" in the R environment.

```
> ls(pattern = "_edg")
[1] "cpi_c_edg"   "gc_c_edg"    "gdp_c_edg"   "t_dep_c_edg"
```

I want to do this:

```
e1 <- window(ts.union(cpi_c_edg, gc_c_edg, gdp_c_edg, t_dep_c_edg))
```

But instead of naming all the series use a code that gets me all the time series with a certain pattern ("_edg") in their name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `mget` to return them in a `list`

```
window(do.call(ts.union, mget(ls(pattern = "_edg"))))
```